# How to detect an empty quosure in rlang?

Tags: r, tidyverse, rlang

```
f <- function(x) enquo(x)

e <- f()
#<quosure: empty>
#~
```

None of these work:

```
> is_empty(e)
[1] FALSE
> is_missing(e)
[1] FALSE
> is_false(e)
[1] FALSE
> is_quosure(e)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `quo_is_missing(x)`, which is an alias for `is_missing(quo_get_expr(x))`.

Comment: I wasted a fair bit of time on this until I noticed/realized that `quo_is_missing(x)` needed to be run *after* `enquo(x)`.  After that, it worked well!

Answer (score 3):

Examining the print method for class `quosure` suggests it gets the "empty" attribute like so:

```
rlang:::env_type(get_env(e))
# [1] "empty"
```

Unfortunately, `env_type` is not exported, and neither are the functions `env_type` calls (ultimately heading to the C function `rlang_is_reference`)

You can get it more directly (`TRUE`/`FALSE`) as:

```
rlang:::is_reference(get_env(e), empty_env())
# [1] TRUE
```

Print method for `quosure`:

```
rlang:::print.quosure
# function (x, ...) 
# {
#     cat(paste0("<quosure: ", env_type(get_env(x)), ">\n"))
#     print(set_attrs(x, NULL))
#     invisible(x)
# }
```

---

I'm not familiar enough with `rlang` to state with certainty, but this appears to be a way to get what you want using exported functions:

```
identical(get_env(e), empty_env())
# [1] TRUE
```

Though I must be missing something, since `rlang:::is_reference` is not using `identical`.

Comment: Or another option may be `any(grepl("empty", capture.output(e)))`

Comment: @akrun I guess that's the other way to do it with exported objects. But seems extremely hack-y. I'd rather see an exported method -- perhaps [file an issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/rlang/issues)? And probably safer would be to `capture.output` of `get_env(e)` and look for `R_EmptyEnv`

Comment: The print method only indicates that the quosure is scoped in the empty environment.

Comment: @lionel I understood OP's question to be: "how does R know `e` is empty when these approaches I took couldn't elicit that?" Thanks for the input!

Comment: @MichaelChirico R doesn't know `e` is empty. To R, `e` is just another user-generated data structure that happens to contain some language-related objects. R is not rlang, rlang is not R.